# Marshalling structures containing reference types/arrays

Tags: winapi, struct, pinvoke, windows-ce, marshalling

I am having problem. This is C definition of the structure:

```
typedef struct _UNIMDM_CHG_DEVCFG {
  DWORD dwCommand; 
  LPCWSTR lpszDeviceClass; 
  LPVARSTRING lpDeviceConfig; 
  DWORD dwOption; 
  DWORD dwValue; 
} UNIMDM_CHG_DEVCFG;
```

I use .NET Compact Framework 3.5 on Windows CE. I tried many ways to marshal this structure, for instance:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct UnimodemChangeDeviceConfiguration
{
    public int dwCommand;

    public byte[] lpszDeviceClass; 

    public byte[] lpDeviceConfig; 

    public int dwOption; 

    public int dwValue;
}
```

The problem is when calling Marshal.SizeOf on an instance of this structure, it throws NotSupportedException. Why? I tried using string for lpszDeviceClass, but again with problems. It seems that pointer types can not get marshaled.

Answer (score 0):

The CF Marshaler cannot handle this.  Your struct contains a pointer to data and when you try to send a byte[] down, the data itself cannot be pinned.

I think the first (LPCWSTR) could be sent in as a string or a StringBuilder (depending on if the data is going in or coming out).

The LPVARSTRING is more complex.  Have you looked at the [OpenNETCF TAPI library](http://tapi.codeplex.com/)?  In structs.cs there is an implementation of the VarString that you could probably just intern in that struct.

Comment: I took a look at it but that class is not written correctly. I wrote one myself and it works. The problem is that in other implementation LPVARSTRING is directly forwarded to the function (not as a part of structure).